# Add a static html page for through in haproxy

Tags: linux, haproxy

Trying to figure out how a static page can be added to a haproxy.

I have a website: https://sky.example.com
And i need to add addition static page https://sky.example.com/testing through Haproxy

My config file haproxy.cfg looks like this:

```
global
   log /var/log loca2 err
   chroot /var/lib/haproxy
   user haproxy
   group haproxy
   daemon
   tune.ssl.default-dh-param 1024
   maxconn 8000de here
defaults
   mode http
   log global
   balance static-rr
   option httplog
   timeout server 300s
   timeout client 300s
   timeout connect 5s
   timeout queue 60s
   retries 3
   timeout http-request 60s
   maxconn 8000
frontend skying
   bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/ssl/testing.pem
   option forwardfor
   acl modelx hdr(host) -i sky.example.com
   use_backend missmay if modelx
   acl is_info_testing path /testing
   use_backend missmay if is_info_testing
backend missmay
   mode http
   errorfile 200 /etc/haproxy/static/testing.html
   server test1_node1 192.168.1.25:78222 check cookie test1_node1
   server test1_node2 192.168.1.26:78222 check cookie test1_node2
```

But it's not working. I get 404 error when I try to get the page https://sky.example.com/testing

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is `listen` and [monitor-uri](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.2/configuration.html#4-monitor-uri).
The following config, placed below `defaults`, serves the static file 200.http on port 80:

```
listen static-file
  bind :80
  monitor-uri /
  errorfile 200 /usr/local/etc/haproxy/errors/200.http
```

Content of 200.http could be:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html

<html><body><h1>200 we are good</h1>
Health checked.
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say what's exactly wrong based on your config file, but I would suggest you to check the haproxy version first. Sometimes different versions could cause the issues like that.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.